# Prototype.js Object doesn't support property or method

Tags: prototype

I can't add events to html select element in prototype. I get "Object doesn't support property or method stopObserving()" error.

```
$$("div.kwTemplate .historial select").each(function(item) {
    item.stopObserving();
    item.observe("focus", this.getHistorialFromExternal.bindAsEventListener(this));
    item.observe("change", this.setHistorialValue.bindAsEventListener(this));
}.bind(this));
```

This is the html:

```
<div class="kwTemplate">
<div class="field historial  idField_15926 idValueauto_15926">
     <label for="_15926">A</label>
     <select>
     <option value="viewHistoric" default="default">Ver ...</option>
     </select>
     <input id="_15926" type="text" class="numeric validate" value=""        maxlength="25" title="Tipo num&#xE9;rico con hist&#xF3;rico de valores" size="28"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance
Javier

Comment: Which version of Prototype? The latest is 1.7.2, April 2014. I put together a fiddle that doesnt throw that error http://jsfiddle.net/t26gD/1/

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Yes, this post is related to this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426531/net-web-browser-component-in-microsoft-office  In outlook, works, in your example works, but in Word, excel and point don't work. It's very strange because all request are the same, only change the office suite.